# My question doesn't belong to me any more

Tags: support

I have asked a question just entering my e-mail address but it doesn't seem to belong me after logging in with same e-mail. What can I do to save my homeless? :/

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106768/is-at-this-weekend-a-serious-mistake#106768

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may have posted the question under the wrong account on EL&U and it wasn't apparent until it migrated over here.

I see your question here in this unregistered profile: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/201452/aliassce but I also see that you have an EL&U account in the registered profile you posted with on ELL: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/201455/aliassce.

You should use the [Contact Us](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link to ask the Stack Exchange team to merge the unregistered account into your main account for you.